# How can I run a Ramaze app on Apache or Litespeed in a ruby enabled environment?

Tags: ruby, litespeed

Also in Cpanel, I have Rubygems and Rails icons to go to those pages.

I can see tutorials for how to setup Sinatra on Apache, but they don't work for Ramaze and I'm using Litespeed server.

For another question, how can I run a [Ramaze app](http://ramaze.net) on Apache in a ruby enabled environment? Maybe Apache and Litespeed are dual-installed.

I added https://gist.github.com/2cf310f39b13f5d6f3b4 as my `.htaccess` file and it did not work for http://compesh.uk.to Cpanel says I also have Apache but online says Litespeed.

Answer (score 0):

You need something more than just apache for a ruby app (phusion passenger for example). Ramaze is a rake based app gem so you should have a look to this side...

First google result for "deploy ramaze" : http://www.codeotaku.com/blog/2009-10/ramaze-and-rack

Good luck ! ;-)

Comment: I added https://gist.github.com/2cf310f39b13f5d6f3b4 as my `.htaccess` file and it did not work for http://compesh.uk.to Cpanel says I also have Apache but online says Litespeed.